# Javascript function button

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have created a button in HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    <p id="demo"></p>           
    <button onclick="button1()">Grayscale</button>
</div>
```

However, I need the button to link to the javascript function below:

```
function clickInfoGreyscale() {
   /* Code */
}
```

How is the button linked to the javascript function?

Comment: `onclick="clickInfoGreyscale()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the click event to fire `clickInfoGreyscale()` instead of `button1`.

```js
function clickInfoGreyscale() {
   /* Code */
  alert('I am grey');
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    <p id="demo"></p>           
    <button onclick="clickInfoGreyscale()">Grayscale</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

İf i understood correct, just replace clickInfoGreyscale with button1 and it will be done.